# SQL remove part of text in a column

Tags: sql-server

I´m trying to get rid of parts of text in a column.
It´s a table with 100.000´s rows and basically its Firstname; Lastname, where Lastname contain Firstname as well, in a lot of them but far from all.

Ex:

> ```
> Firstname Lastname
> Magnus    Johansson
> Anders    Anders Jansson
> Stefan    Stefan Andersson
> Emma      Svensson
> Annelie   Annelie Nilsson
> ```

I would like to clean it up to:

> ```
> Firstname Lastname
> Magnus    Johansson
> Anders    Jansson
> Stefan    Andersson
> Emma      Svensson
> Annelie   Nilsson
> ```

I have tried using SUBSTR and RIGHT with a few alterations, with no success

```
RIGHT(Lastname, LEN(Lastname) - LEN(Firstname)) as New_Lastname
```

RIGHT as well as SUBSTR and others I have looked at requires a fixed int value to determine what should be replaced/removed.

Anyone know how to proceed with a variable length on the text that need to be altered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [**REPLACE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
REPLACE (Lastname, Firstname + ' ', '')
```

If `Firstname` is contained in `Lastname` then it will simply be replaced by an empty string.

Note: You need to add an extra space to the `string_pattern` of `REPLACE` so as to avoid replacing any `Firsname` values that are part of `Lastname`, like in this case:

```
Firstname Lastname
-------------------
Mark      Markuson
```

As a final note, you might have to apply [**LTRIM**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) to `REPLACE`, like:

```
LTRIM(REPLACE (Lastname, Firstname + ' ', ''))
```

so as to trim any leading spaces after replace has taken place.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b41a4/3)

Comment: This would seem to leave the extra space remaining in the `Lastname` column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was in course of editing my answer when you posted the comment. Please check the edit I made.

Comment: Great answer and extremely fast post.

Comment: Well, trailing blanks seem to have been the bad guy here. When getting rid of those (adding LTRIM/RTRIM), both REPLACE and RIGHT seem to work. Thanks for your help. :)